# Advance Custom Field Multiple Get Field Code in the same file not working

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the Advance Custom Field plugin to add custom fields to one of my plugins which is a custom post type. I have this code where I used the `get_field()`twice. The problem I am having is that only one of them works - the first one I created for that custom post type. 
The second one only works when I delete the first one from the code. Please see the code below.

Example:

```
<div class="ats-awsm awsm-grid-modal awsm-grid">
        <?php while ($team->have_posts()): $team->the_post();
            $teamdata = $this->get_options('awsm_team_member', $team->post->ID);?>
                <div id="" class="awsm-grid-card">
                    <div class="author_avatar">
                        <a href="#" id="tigger-style-<?php echo $id.'-'.$team->post->ID; ?>" class="awsm-modal-trigger" data-trigger="#modal-style-<?php echo $id.'-'.$team->post->ID; ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $this->team_thumbnail($team->post->ID);?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>">
                            <?php $this->checkprint('<span>%s</span>', $teamdata['awsm-team-designation']);?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="awsm-personal-info-container">
                        <div class="awsm-personal-info">
                            <a href="#" id="tigger-style-<?php echo $id.'-'.$team->post->ID; ?>" class="awsm-modal-trigger" data-trigger="#modal-style-<?php echo $id.'-'.$team->post->ID; ?>">
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <span><?php _e( 'Click for Quick Profile', '' ) ?></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="shortdesc"><?php $this->checkprint('<p>%s</p>', $teamdata['awsm-team-short-desc']);?></div>
                        <div class="authorsarticles">
                            <h4><?php _e( 'Articles', '' ) ?></h4>
                            <?php the_field('userpost_shortcode'); ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/author' ) ); ?>" class="more_btn"><?php _e( 'More from this writer', '' ) ?></a>
                            <div><?php the_field('contributors_page'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
        </div><!-- .grid -->
```

Everything is right in the backend but I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Have you tried adding the ID to the `the_field()` function? So maybe like `the_field('userpost_shortcode', $team->post->ID)` -- you shouldn't HAVE to do that, but might help...

Comment: Your suggestion worked although it is strange that I have to do this since the '$team->post->ID' is already contained within the loop.

Comment: I would agree it is strange. I will post as an answer if you wouldn't mind accepting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `$team->post->ID` to the `the_field()` function. So it will look like: `the_field('userpost_shortcode', $team->post->ID)`